# || operator not working as expected in EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have this EJS code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/<%= css || 'default' %>.css" />
```

I thought that, when `css` was `undefined`, this would evaluate to `"/public/stylesheets/default.css"`, but instead it throws the error

```
css is not defined
```

Why? Is this a quirk of EJS, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It may be useful to see how you use and pass data to the template.

Comment: It says that `css` is *not defined* rather than `undefined`. Two different concepts. If it's not defined, it's never declared and/or cannot be reached from the current + enclosing scopes. `undefined` means it's *declared* but no value is assigned to it.

Comment: @customcommander In this case, I didn't pass any data to the template.

Comment: @VLAZ OHH. I just put a `<% let css %>` on the line above, and that fixed it. Thank you, I had no idea there was a distinction.

Comment: @VLAZ is most likely right here. You get the same error in plain JS with `css || 42`. If the variable isn't declared in the first place, trying to accessing it will cause an error. Perhaps `typeof css === 'undefined' ? 42 : css` would work

Comment: Oop. `<% let css %>` won't work, because that will overwrite the value if it _is_ passed in. What a conundrum.

Comment: @customcommander You're right, that does work. Thank you.

Comment: @customcommander would you like to post that as an answer? That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As **VLAZ** says:

> It says that `css` is *not defined* rather than `undefined`. Two different concepts. If it's not defined, it's never declared and/or cannot be reached from the current and enclosing scopes. `undefined` means it's *declared* but no value is assigned to it.

I was able to solve my problem using **customcommander**'s solution:

Rather than

```js
css || 'default'
```

which throws an error, use

```js
typeof css === 'undefined' ? 'default' : css
```